# How to install PostgreSQL on Windows Server Core

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-core

Is it possible to install PostgreSQL on Windows Server Core?

https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ lists two methods for installing PostgreSQL on Windows.

1) Interactive installer by EnterpriseDB
2) Graphical installer by BigSQL

Installer 1) can be run with `--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none` but the process somehow gets stuck and never finishes.

Installer 2) fails already during its unzipping script.

A [old closed Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193927/how-to-install-postgresql-on-windows-using-command-prompt) helpfully suggests using [plain binary archives](https://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and hints at some additional steps that are required for using these. Is that the generally recommended approach that works on Windows Server Core? What are the exact detailed steps? Are they documented somewhere beyond:

- [initdb docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-initdb.html)
- [pg_ctl docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pg-ctl.html)

But running any of these binaries fail with no output.

Comment: The necessary steps are also mentioned in this post.

Comment: The binaries don't work: installing vcredist helps. So a better approach appears to be using 1) with `--extract-only`, run the extracted `installer\vcredist_x64.exe /install /passive / norestart`, and *then* use `initdb` and `pg_ctl`.

Answer (score 1):

postgresql-14.2-2-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "" --servicename "postgreSQL" --servicepassword "" --serverport 5432